# How can I change the value of variable in a exec() function?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code:

```
def test():
    c = 0
    exec('c = 4 + 5')
    print('result', c)
```

The value of `c` is 0. What can I do to fix it, let the value of `c` changed in `exec()` function?

Answer (score 4):

In cpython, you can't do what you want inside a function. That's because a function's local namespace can't be easily edited by other code (editing the dictionary returned by `locals()` doesn't do it). If instead you call `exec` from the top level of your module, it will work as you want, but it is still probably a bad idea.

A better approach may be to use a namespace dictionary. You can pass it to `exec` and the change will appear there, rather than in the function's local namespace or the module's global namespace:

```
def test():
    namespace = {'c': 0}
    exec('c = 4 + 5', namespace)
    print('result', namespace['c'])
```

Comment: Thank You. And what mean with "If instead you call exec from the top level of your module", I can't understand it...can you show me a example?

Comment: @xinchen I mean that your code would work if the `exec` and other lines were not inside the `test` function. That's because an `exec` call with no namespace arguments is equivalent to `exec(whatever, globals(), locals())`. Inside a function, you can't usefully save values to the dictionary returned by `locals`, so that doesn't do you much good. But at top level, `locals()` returns the same dictionary as `globals()`, and you can modify that dictionary and see the results in the global namespace.